# Extranet users in Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I would like to give my Extranet users access to edit fields in some pages using the page editor, but how do I do this? I've managed to give the user access to the page editor but I can not for the life of me figure out to make the fields editable. I see the ribbon, but they cannot edit fields

The User has the following role: 
`sitecore\Author`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting the error that you "do not have the priviledges for that language," you should check the user or role's permission on the language item.

EDIT: Check Language Read and Language Write access to /Sitecore/System/Languages/en. In the Security and/or Access Viewer tool, use the Columns ribbon button to add the Language Read and Language Write columns to the display.

Comment: I have looked and looked but I vant find anything that is named languages, Can you point mé in the right direction?

Comment: It was totally what I needed, was beginning to think that I couldn't assign extranet users, page editor priviledges thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the users Write access to the content in question? The best way to see if you have the security configured correctly is to use the Access Viewer. At the top left you can select the context user/role you wish to check the security for. In your case, select one of the users and see what permissions they have.  Remember as best practice you should set all permissions on a role rather than on individual users.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that, when I apply the same rights to a Sitecore domain user it works perfectly... It says I cannot edit the item because I do not have the priviledges for that language, whatever that means. I know about the roles but this is just for testing on my development machine.